Is there a function to add a header to the first column (row names) in a matrix?
I am trying to figure out how to take this matrix and add a label to the column containing the row names (since this is not treated as a "column" when using the colnames command).
Here is my code (df and table names are generic so as to avoid identifying the dataset I am using which contains sensitive data). Note the top left of the output is empty at the moment. My goal is to populate that empty space with the word "Years".
#making sure labels are properly ordered
matrix1 <- as.matrix(table(df$yrsvar)[c("< 1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "10+", "Don't Know")])

#columnnames
colnames(matrix1) <- (c("Percent"))

#making vertical, setting as percentages
as.matrix(prop.table(matrix1)) %>% '*' (100) %>% round(2)

Output:
           Percent
< 1          12.39
1             2.65
2             8.85
3             7.96
4             6.19
5             5.31
6             2.65
7             2.65
8             4.42
9             1.77
10            7.08
10+          36.28
Don't Know    1.77

I have tried using the colnames command but this column is not treated as a column that can be labelled.
I have tried some generic solutions but all require me to convert my matrix to a dataframe which I would like to avoid. Preservation as a matrix is important here.

No. There is no Header. And that’s not a column hence colnames<- would not affect it. There are “dimnames” in the attributes and you can modify them with the appropriate functions. See ?attributes<-

What you’re looking for would be to create a print.matrix function that would print some text for the rownames. Except don’t try. There’s something that breaks when you try that. At the moment the function that will be operable is print.default

@IRTFM - won't dimnames(matrix1) <- list("Years" = rownames(matrix1), "Percent") allow printing a name Years for the row names ?

Here's a related question where a method to alter the printing of a matrix is illustrated. (but it doesn't do what you're asking and I don't think it's a duplicate.) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955488/how-can-i-suppress-not-print-line-numbers/30955763#30955763

What's wrong with a data frame or tibble where the first column is called "Years" and contains the names in an easily manipulated format? Matrices can be a bit faster if you are doing certain complex operations, but in your case it looks like a data frame would be perfect.

@thelatemail should have posted but I put an MCVE for the record:
mdat <- matrix(c(1,2,3, 11,12,13), 
nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE, 
dimnames = list('rows'=c("row1", "row2"), 
                       c("C.1", "C.2", "C.3"))); mdat



#Naming both the rownames and the colnames
mdat <- matrix(c(1,2,3, 11,12,13), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE,
               dimnames = list("rows"= c("row1", "row2"),
                               "cols"=c("C.1", "C.2", "C.3")))
mdat

I guess I will need to play around to make a function that alters the name of the rownames object inside a matrix that already exists, but that shouldn't be too hard. One will need to work on the attributes component of the matrix.
For an existing matrix mdat one can use this to add a name for the "column" of rownames:
#Generalized for a multi-column matrix 
dimnames(mdat) <- list("Years" = rownames(mdat), dimnames(mdat)[[2]])
#---------
 mdat
      
Years  C.1 C.2 C.3
  row1   1   2   3
  row2  11  12  13

#--- the next succeeds but is not quite as elegant or complete
names( attributes(mdat)$dimnames ) <- list("rows", NULL)

#---
> mdat
      NULL
rows   C.1 C.2 C.3
  row1   1   2   3
  row2  11  12  13


You can use a combination of dimnames and names as below:
mat <- matrix(sample(3), 3)
mat
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    3
[3,]    2

Add column names:
colnames(mat) <- "numbers"
mat
     numbers
[1,]       1
[2,]       3
[3,]       2

Add rownames
rownames(mat) <- letters[1:3]
mat
  numbers
a       1
b       3
c       2

Add column title alone
names(dimnames(mat))[2] <-"columns"
mat
   columns
NA  numbers
  a       1
  b       3
  c       2

Add row title alone
names(dimnames(mat))[1] <- "rows"
mat
    columns
rows numbers
   a       1
   b       3
   c       2

Change titles simultaneously:
names(dimnames(mat)) <- c("AA", "BB")
mat
   BB
AA  numbers
  a       1
  b       3
  c       2

ETC...
